# lighttpd authentication and rewrite on same url not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, lighttpd, mod-auth

I can't seem to get both authentication and rewriting on the same url. If I disable one, the other works. Is this possible in lighttpd?

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "www\.example\.com$" {
   auth.require = (
     "/prettyurl" =>
     (
      "method" => "basic",
      "realm" => "Password reqired",
      "require" => "valid-user"
     )
   )
   url.rewrite = (
         "/prettyurl" => "/index.php?foo=bar&goo=car"
   )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually encapsulate `auth.require` inside a `$HTTP["url"]`. Something like that:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "www\.example\.com$" {
  url.rewrite = (
    "/prettyurl" => "/index.php?foo=bar&goo=car"
  )

  $HTTP["url"] == "/index.php" {
    $HTTP["querystring"] == "foo=bar&goo=car" {
      auth.require = ( "" =>
        (
          "method"  => "basic",
          "realm"   => "Password reqired",
          "require" => "valid-user"
        )
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: with this code the rewrite works, but i am not prompted for a password

Comment: Try to remove the `^` from `$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/prettyurl" {`. Also, can you provide real example of your url? Maybe, once the url is rewrited, you must catch the rewrited url (ie: `/index.php?foo=bar&goo=car`) instead of the `/prettyurl`.

Comment: removing `^` didnt help. i am using this exact conf file. only difference i have is the domain-name. If I comment out the rewrite I get prompted for a password and then get a 404. If I leave the rewrite in it goes to index.php without authenticating. It really seems as though it won't allow me to do both rewrite and auth! I appreciate your help.

Comment: this works if i remove `?foo=bar&goo=car` but I need to pass the variables.

Comment: It's because `url` doesn't containt the query string, so you have to combine `url` and `querystring` to match the url.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this. It seems that neither `auth.require` nor `$HTTP["url"]` will not match on the query string part of the url.

First make a symbolic link

```
ln -s index.php index_auth.php
```

Then in lighttpd conf:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "www\.example\.com" {
    url.rewrite = (
       "/prettyurl-auth" => "/index_auth.php?foo=bar",
       "/prettyurl-noauth" => "/index.php?goo=car"
    )
    auth.require = ( "/index_auth.php" =>
      (
        "method"  => "basic",
        "realm"   => "Password reqired",
        "require" => "valid-user"
      )
    )
}
```

If there is a beter way, please let me know!